# Select order by the most common categories (Mysql, Php)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables in my Mysql-database:

First: `articles`:

```
 Id |    page_title   | description 
-------------------------------------
  1 | Bob Dylan       | Lorem Ipsum..
  2 | Paul Mccartney  | Lorem Ipsum..
  3 | John Lennon     | Lorem Ipsum..
  4 | Pierce Brosnan  | Lorem Ipsum..
  5 | Microsoft       | Lorem Ipsum..
  6 | Apple           | Lorem Ipsum..
  7 | Google          | Lorem Ipsum..
  8 | Steve Jobs      | Lorem Ipsum..
  9 | Neil Young      | Lorem Ipsum..
```

Second `categories`:

```
 Id |     page_id     | category_name
-------------------------------------
  1 | 1               | musician
  2 | 2               | beatles_member
  3 | 3               | beatles_member
  4 | 5               | company
  5 | 6               | company
  6 | 7               | company
  7 | 8               | entrepreneur
  8 | 9               | guitarist
  9 | 2               | pianist
 10 | 4               | actor
 11 | 4               | jamesbond_actor
 12 | 8               | apple_ceo
 13 | 2               | musician
```

Now I have an article, for example `Paul McCartney` with the `Id 2`.
His categories are `(musician, pianist, beatles_member)`.
And much more just in this example 3 cause the page size.

Now I want to have 5 other articles from The `articles` table which have the most common categories. In this example the 3 above.

My try to do that with mysql is:

```
$categories = "'musician', 'pianist', 'beatles_member'";
```

`SELECT * FROM articles a LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.page_id = a.Id WHERE c.category_name IN ($categories) LIMIT 5`

But with this, i just get the articles which have every of the categories which `Paul McCartney` have (are often not more than 3 results). I want the Articles which have the most common categories. Anybody an idea?

Comment: Define most common please. The following query will give you the most common category.
`SELECT category_name, COUNT(*) FROM categories GROUP BY category_name` or are you looking for a way to rank each category in relation to the input categories you give? Sort of like marketbasket analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution using `GROUP BY` & `HAVING`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM pages p
LEFT JOIN categoires c ON c.page_id = p.id
WHERE c.category_name IN (%categories%)
GROUP BY p.page_id
HAVING COUNT(c.id) = %number_of_categories%
```

Paste the list of your categories instead of `%categories%` and the number of categories instead of `%number_of_categories%`.

As a result, you will get a list of pages which have all of the specified categories. If some page will not have at least one category from the `%categories%` list, then it will be excluded from the selection because of `COUNT(c.id) = %number_of_categories%` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You must make a subquery to your most common category contained in the IN

```
SELECT * FROM articles a LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.page_id = a.Id WHERE c.category_name IN (SELECT category_name FROM categorie [...]  LIMIT 3 ) LIMIT 5
```

I do not want to do all the work in your place.

Comment: Note that `LEFT JOIN c... WHERE c` is the same as `INNER JOIN c...`